# How do i make regex for final occurence of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a regex of that search for the final occurence of given alphabet in a string.

```
import re
string = "Hello stackoverflow"
[print(re.sub('o', '*', string))]
```

i'm expecting "Hello stackoverfl*w" as the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution:

```
re.sub(r"(.*)o", r"\1*", string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reverse the string, do the replacement once, and return the re-reversed string:

```
re.sub('o','*',string[::-1],1)[::-1]
#                           ^ this means do the replacement only once
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `re.sub` for a regex option:

```
string = "Hello stackoverflow"
output = re.sub(r'^(.*)o(.*)$', '\\1*\\2', string)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
Hello stackoverfl*w
```